# PHP calling function from another php file without including it

Tags: php, call

I have 4 php files that are `"index.php"`, `"config.php"`, `"redirect.php"`, & `"main.php"`
and i defined a call fuction in `"config.php"` file and also included it in `"index.php"`  so whenever i call that function it works on `"redirect.php"` file as well as on `"main.php"` file

But i created an another php file name `"my-redirect.php"` so i want to call that function on this `"my-redirect.php"` php file and i also included it in `"index.php"` but i don't want that page to be appear on main site i just want that call function to work on that file, it's actually a other page of site! So how can i do this?

Comment: Just create separate file "functions.php" with all your functions and include it to files uses that functions.

Comment: seems like a problem with your architecture, if your using classes you should look into autoloaders like PSR-0  https://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/  if your doing it procedural you should look at more Object Oriented method of coding IMO, ( but I cant stand procedural programming )

Comment: @LukaszTkacz i tried it not works @ ArtisticPhoenix it's not class member tho :/

Comment: @VickyMalhotra it can't "not works". If you have functions in one file and just include this file in other (in start of file), you can use all these functions

Comment: @LukaszTkacz got it, it works when i include that php file with that config file on one php file but i need to use 2 php file(1 for main content 2 for showing) any idea to include in the same file? :|

Comment: Shit man didn't even thought to include that config function in the main file, it's working now :)